# Can a .NET Core Web app consume .NET Framework class libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core, class-library

I'm planning on migrating an old website built in WebForms to a .NET Core web application. But there are a few projects in the solution that are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 that are currently being used by the WebForm project. Is it possible to still uses these libraries in a .NET Core web app?

Comment: What are the libraries?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Theyre .NET Framework Class Libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to if your .Net Core project is also [targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks) the `net462` or later Full .NET Framework.

Comment: How do I ensure that? I apologize a lot of this project level detail is new to me.

Comment: Read the link I embeded: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks

Comment: So a .NET Framework Class Library can be used by a .NET Core Web app if the .NET Core project builds for both .net core and .net framework? Do I have that correct?

Comment: Not both.  If you want to use full .NET Framework libraries, you can only target .NET Framework, unless you use multi-targeting and provide alternate implementations of those libraries for the .Net Core targets.

Comment: I see so I have to change the .NET Core web app to target .netframework instead of .netcore.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a .NET Framework implementation.  The .NET Core web app would be multi-platform but .NET Framework is Windows only and thus the result needs to Windows only.